# IIS 7, MVC2 Web Service, HTTP 405 Error on PUT

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-mvc-2

This is a similar question as [IIS 7.5, Web Service and HTTP 405 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287330/iis-7-5-web-service-and-http-405-error) but a little different. Instead of a WCF web service, I've got an MVC2 web service that returns a 405 error when a PUT is used in the request. And, in my case, POST works just fine.

I'm guessing I need to either add or tweak an IIS 7 Handler Mapping to get PUT to work but my hosting provider hasn't been much help. Anyone out there run into this and know how to get PUTs to work in an MVC2 web service running in IIS 7? My apologies if this has already been answered, I've been searching all day and haven't found the magical answer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem, and the solution was adding an element into  section in the Web.config file:

```
<remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
```

Comment: thx, simple and worked! there's so many posts out there for this, and this should be the official answer for them all

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://serverfault.com/questions/93424/how-to-enable-put-and-delete-in-iis7/93428#93428

[dario-solera:](https://serverfault.com/users/4373/dario-solera)

> You can take a look at the "Handlers
>   Mappings" sections at either the
>   server or site level (IIS group).
>   Select a mapping for an extension
>   (e.g. .aspx) and select "Edit" from
>   the context menu. The "Verbs" tab
>   allows you to specify verbs to accept.

Comment: Thanks, Greg. Unfortunately, I don't know what mapping to select. I'm working with a RESTful MVC2 web service so there really isn't any file extension associated with the urls. I've tried tweaking the ExtensionlessUrl-Integrated-4.0 mapping, adding the PUT verb to it, but that didn't help. Perhaps I'll need to create a new one to allow PUTs?