# HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed -- POST Fails

Tags: html, http-post

I have an HTML web page that should submit back to itself, but constantly fails if method="POST".  It works with GET, but we really want POST.  I have ripped out all of the code until there is nothing left but an input and a submit, but it always gets the 405 error.  This temp web page is as stripped down as I can make it.

I am running this test off my PC running IIS 7.

```
<form id="form1" action="PhoneTest3.html" method="POST">
    <label for="contactPhoneExt">Contact Phone: </label>
    <input id="contactPhoneExt" name="contactPhoneExt" />
    <br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IIS 7.5, Web Service and HTTP 405 error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287330/iis-7-5-web-service-and-http-405-error)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it is truly an HTML page (and not a scripted page hidden behind an .HTML extension) then you can't post to it.

You can use GET and pass values through the command line that Javascript can read off, however.

EDIT: More details.

`GET` passes values through the URL.  They become part of the URL and can be bookmarked, copied, easily modified, etc.

`POST,` on the other hand, feeds values through what programmers call `stdin.`  `stdin` is *like* a file that a program reads and then processes.  Much larger amounts of data may be passed this way, but it takes a program running on the server to be able to access any of that data -- thus, whatever local file receiving post data *must* be able to run on the server.

It gets confusing because web servers can be set up to show an `.html` extension on their files, yet those files are actually `PHP` scripts that run.

Comment: I understand that I can't do a whole lot with it, but I can not even POST to it and loose the passed data?

Comment: @JohnatDaytonSuperior: Just updated my answer to provide for info

Comment: I was simply expecting to loose the data, not actually fail!  I changed the extension from html to asp and it rolled right through.
Thanks!

Comment: If you were planning on loosing the data anyways, why not just make a regular link instead of using a form?