# PHP file upload Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-405

Working closely with this [W3 Schools's guide](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp), I'm trying to upload an image via a `<form>` on an `.aspx` page to a "server", using `PHP`. The "server" is actually my localhost. The form is being submitted but then I get the 405 error. I checked the response headers and I can see:

> Allow:GET, HEAD, OPTIONS, TRACE

If this is really the issue, how do I change this?

NOTE: My `PHP` code and `HTML` content are an exact copy of the example in the link provided.

Comment: Your localhost server doesn't allow HTTP Method `POST` which is used to upload files.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Question was and is - how do I change this?

Comment: The question is, what is your webserver? Apache, Nginx, Lighthttp (or whatever it's called) or something else?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois I don't really have a server... This is just an exercise project hosted locally on my computer.

Comment: Your computer is running a webserver software. So what did you install to achieve that?

Comment: The only things I'm using are Visual Studio 2015 and Google Chrome.

Comment: If you don't have a webserver software installed, you can't run PHP. That's probably why you're not allowed to use `PHP` because the software who catches the connection can't handle it (the heat).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89196/discussion-between-ozw-and-charlotte-dunois).

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12221742/1301076

Comment: The issue is an IIS configuration problem. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287330/iis-7-5-web-service-and-http-405-error