# Using GWT getting 405 error message on IIS 7.5

Tags: ajax, gwt, iis-7.5

I have inherited a project that is using GWT to post login information via a form. According to Firebug, its coming back with a 405 error.

I have tried the directions on: [IIS 7.5, Web Service and HTTP 405 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287330/iis-7-5-web-service-and-http-405-error)

That didn't fix the problem. I turned on Failed Request tracking and this is the error that I see:

MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS
Warning

ModuleName="StaticFileModule", Notification="EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER", HttpStatus="405", HttpReason="Method Not Allowed", HttpSubStatus="0", ErrorCode="Incorrect function.
 (0x80070001)", ConfigExceptionInfo=""

Thanks!

Comment: You need to add more detail to your question. What happens in GWT Debug mode?

Comment: I get the same result. A 405 error.

Comment: Attach code snippets and probably you will have more detailed logs.

Comment: Sure do you just want to see a snip of the login function?